# How to plot Tensor flow activation functions in a range of inputs

Tags: python, tensorflow, plot, representation

I really like to have 2D representation of activation functions in tensor flow.
for example, plotting :

```
(tf.nn.sigmoid(
```

for a range of inputs, something like the image:
[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvqBG.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tensorboard was not designed for plots like this, so it is awkward, but you can do something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# Create '/tmp/activations' directory or point to some other directory
summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(logdir='/tmp/activations')

x_numpy = np.linspace(start=-6.0, stop=6.0, num=120)
x = tf.constant(x_numpy)
y = tf.nn.sigmoid(x)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    y_numpy = sess.run(y)

for x_i, y_i in zip(x_numpy, y_numpy):

    # Create a tensorboard summary with sigmoid output as the value
    # and sigmoid input as a step (which is normally
    # the `global_step` tensor). Tensorboards plots step in x-axis.
    # step must be an integer. So, we multiply x_i by 1M and convert 
    # it to int. This should be precise enough. In the plot,
    # just ignore the "M" suffix.
    value = tf.Summary.Value(tag='sigmoid', simple_value=y_i) 
    summary_writer.add_event(
        event=tf.summary.Event(summary=tf.Summary(value=[value]),
                               step=int(1000000 * x_i)))

summary_writer.close()

# Point tensorboad to '/tmp/activations'
```

[image]

Comment: as i know tf.summary.FileWriter.add_event() has just one argument: event https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/summary/FileWriter

Comment: @ArefRiant Thanks! edited.This is what happens when you write the code from memory and don't try it :).

Comment: thanks, i really tried to make the code work, first of all i had problem with the error: "Positional argument are not allowed" after solving that, i have problem with error:TypeError: -1.0 has type numpy.float64, but expected one of: int, long

Comment: @ArefRiant Sorry about that. Edited the code. Should work now.